# Output file is not generated with system call from matlab

Tags: c++, c, matlab

I have a C++ program that generate some output files using `fopen ("./myfile.txt","w")`. Everything is fine and working and I can see the output files.

I want to run this program from MATLAB and call it many times to test the output files, using MATLAB system call: `system ('./myprog')`. Although the output is correct but the output file is not generated.
I have seen similar problem [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/203981-using-matlab-command-from-vs2013-c-system-call-to-exeute-a-script-fprintf-issue). However, I could not solve the problem with setting the environment variables.

I tried different mode of addressing also I tried this `system (ls > out)` and the file is generated.

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute pathname (starting with "/") for your output file?   It's likely that the current directory is different when you run your program from inside matlab versus standalone.

Comment: Yes. I am using CentOS and I tried both absolute and relative addressing

Comment: Could it be that MATLAB runs as another user that has no write access to the target directory? What happens when you write to `/tmp/your-output.txt`?

Comment: Matlab version 9.2

Comment: @meaning-matters I tried writing other files form Matlab on that directory and it is ok. I dont know what happens when I am trying from inside C++

Comment: @Aznaveh Yeah, that's true.

Comment: Try adding some tests inside your C++ program. `fopen` is failing. You should always check its return value anyway. If it fails, check the `errno` value to see why it fails.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I already check if fopen fails. That’s not returning any error messages. And outside matlab it works fine everything seems similar inside but the files are not there. I already searched outside the current directory and didn’t find the files there either.

Comment: Either the files are created, or `fopen` errors and sets `errno`. So if `fopen` doesn't error, then the files are created. They could be somewhere you don't expect them to be, but they are somewhere.

Comment: I have not done anything special but everything is working with my matlab code. I have not added any code; maybe my problem was in somewhere else.